# Which rules define how to pronounce a consonant?

Tags: etymology, differences, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

My question might appear silly and pointless to some, but I find it pretty interesting myself.

If we look at the word '*circus*', it has 3 consonants and 2 vowels. However, the 2 *c* in the words are pronounced in a different manner. The first has sound of *s* as in '*hiss*', while the second has the sound of *k* as in '*kit*'.

Also, the vowel *i* and the vowel *u* are pronounced the same, although they are not the same. Both, in this case, are pronounced as *u* in '*cut*' or '*upper*'.

There are even more examples of such confusions, such as the use of *ph* vs *f* in  '*graph*' and '*fish*'.

Why is it so? Why is it so that in English, such discrepancies in pronunciations exist? Is it because most English words are derived from different languages, Latin and Greek?

PS: On a side note, I just want to say that in my native language, Hindi, it doesn't happen. Even if such differences do exist and I just don't know about it, they're rare.

Comment: Pterodactyl, gnome, knight. I before E except after C and the sound of A as in neighbor and weigh. *Weird Science* ruins everything.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a false premise.

Comment: This is Too Broad, a Duplicate, and is based on a false premise. There are no such spelling-to-pronunciation rules that can be explained to you here in a simple Q&A format.  You should therefore just PRETEND THAT THERE ARE NO RULES THAT YOU WILL EVER UNDERSTAND without a multiyear study of very complex and diverse historical matters related to Middle English, French, Latin, Greek, and a great deal of other languages as well. Until you do that, nothing will make sense. You must every learn each and every new word you encounter by looking it up, just like the rest of us have had to do. Sorry.

Comment: Neither the _i_, nor the _u_ in _circus_ is pronounced like the _u_ in _uppercut_. They’re not pronounced the same, either.

Comment: So does this mean that there's no hard-and-fast rule to how a word is supposed to be pronounced, based upon it's spelling?

Comment: No. Seriously. Slaughter doesn't rhyme with laughter. Height and weight don't rhyme. As you wonder and wander and ponder, you'll reach and react to the result.

Comment: @zhirzh [Yes of course it means ***precisely*** that.](http://ncf.idallen.com/english.html) Whatever led you to believe otherwise? The final line in the poem is the soundest advice possible: “GIVE IT UP!”

Comment: If you know a word's origin (Latinate, Germanic, other) it *is* usually possible to determine how it should be pronounced from the spelling. Spelling originally reflected regional pronunciation; a word could be spelled in many different ways! (More than two dozen ways to spell the Old English word for 'sister', e.g.)  Normalized spelling is an attempt to "fix" that problem. But language changes over time. So even if we were to "fix" the  spelling system by mapping it to today's *preferred* pronunciations, it would eventually become out-of-sync. That's a problem with phonetic spelling systems.

Comment: The answer to your several questions is [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/pronunciation-vs-spelling/info).

Comment: @tchrist. That was a good read. Plus, I feel like my question's been answered. I guess I was just irritated at the differences in spelling and the pronunciations - it's all gone now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The English writing system is at fault and every native speaker knows that.

> "In a Garden-of-Eden writing system, you would have a single letter for each speech-sound and one speech-sound for each single letter."   [Language Myths](http://seas3.elte.hu/coursematerial/LazarAPeter/Bauer_-_Trudgill_-_Language_Myths(1999).pdf)
> German is much more like that than English, and several other languages too.

Although a large number of English words do follow such pattern - best, help, jam, limit, map, win, rob, yet, to mention just a few - most English words prove that there are too few letters for too many speech sounds. The reasons for this have to do with English words having different origins, pronunciation changes throughout the centuries, the difficulties that a spelling reform would face, etc.  To have a better explanation, see [Language Myths](http://seas3.elte.hu/coursematerial/LazarAPeter/Bauer_-_Trudgill_-_Language_Myths(1999).pdf)

> **humour**
>
> British worker - "I can't work today, sir. I have diarrhoea."
>
> American boss - "Diarrhea? That's dreadful. You could have sent me a sick note."
>
> British worker - "I can't spell it, sir."

Comment: Might have worked even better if the poor bloke had been asthmatic and gotten a phthisical cough…

Answer (score 0):

English is an amalgamation of Germanic and Latinate words.  Pronunciation may vary depending upon the word's origin.

Often the way a consonant is pronounced is determined by the vowel it precedes.